# How to convert SoftwareBitmap from Bgra8 to JPEG in Windows UWP

Tags: windows, uwp, c++-cx

How to convert SoftwareBitmap from Bgra8 to JPEG in Windows UWP. GetPreviewFrameAsync function is used to get videoFrame data in Bgra8. What is going wrong in the following code?. I am getting jpeg size 0.

```
    auto previewProperties = static_cast<MediaProperties::VideoEncodingProperties^>
        (mediaCapture->VideoDeviceController->GetMediaStreamProperties(Capture::MediaStreamType::VideoPreview));
    unsigned int videoFrameWidth = previewProperties->Width;
    unsigned int videoFrameHeight = previewProperties->Height;
    FN_TRACE("%s videoFrameWidth %d videoFrameHeight %d\n",
        __func__, videoFrameWidth, videoFrameHeight);

    // Create the video frame to request a SoftwareBitmap preview frame
    auto videoFrame = ref new VideoFrame(BitmapPixelFormat::Bgra8, videoFrameWidth, videoFrameHeight);

    // Capture the preview frames
    return create_task(mediaCapture->GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame))
        .then([this](VideoFrame^ currentFrame)
    {
        // Collect the resulting frame
        auto previewFrame = currentFrame->SoftwareBitmap;

        auto inputStream = ref new Streams::InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        create_task(BitmapEncoder::CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder::JpegEncoderId, inputStream))
            .then([this, previewFrame, inputStream](BitmapEncoder^ encoder)
        {
            encoder->SetSoftwareBitmap(previewFrame);
            encoder->FlushAsync();

            FN_TRACE("jpeg size %d\n", inputStream->Size);
            Streams::Buffer^ data = ref new Streams::Buffer(inputStream->Size);
            create_task(inputStream->ReadAsync(data, (unsigned int)inputStream->Size, InputStreamOptions::None));
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bitmap​Encoder.FlushAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder#Windows_Graphics_Imaging_BitmapEncoder_FlushAsync) method is a asynchronous method. We should consume it like the following:

```
// Capture the preview frames
return create_task(mediaCapture->GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame))
    .then([this](VideoFrame^ currentFrame)
{
    // Collect the resulting frame
    auto previewFrame = currentFrame->SoftwareBitmap;

    auto inputStream = ref new Streams::InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

    return create_task(BitmapEncoder::CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder::JpegEncoderId, inputStream))
        .then([this, previewFrame](BitmapEncoder^ encoder)
    {
        encoder->SetSoftwareBitmap(previewFrame);
        return encoder->FlushAsync();
    }).then([this, inputStream]()
    {

        FN_TRACE("jpeg size %d\n", inputStream->Size);
        //TODO
    });
});
```

Then you should be able to get the right size. For more info, please see [Asynchronous programming in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-in-cpp-universal-windows-platform-apps).